# Postgres 9.1 - can't create extension for adminpack to work with pgadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working on a Rails app and have successfully loaded postgresql9.1 on my macX.  Rails works fine with postgres, but now want to fully use pgadmin3 to update tables.

Pgadmin3 indicates I need to add adminpack -- the file is already in the postgres dir on  my mac.  Postgres guide (and the command line) say that a "CREATE EXTENSION --adminpack" command is needed.  I've tried many different approaches and can't figure it out.  I'm first time postgres user so any help would be a life saver!

The terminal command/response is below:

> $ CREATE EXTENSION adminpack--1.0
>   -bash: CREATE: command not found

Everything else with the postgres db/admin/rails seems to be working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack". The "--1.0" and so on is put in by the Postgres server. viz.:

```
steve@postgres@[local] =# create extension adminpack;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  i tried this at the top level psql $ prompt, but doesn't work.  Do I need to issue command at the database level vs. server level?

Comment: psql doesn't really distinguish between "server level" and "database level". However, to work with pgadmin I believe you need to create the extension on the "postgres" database, not any of the others. Are you getting an error from psql or just still getting the message box from pgadmin?

Comment: thanks, i got it to work on by logging into a specific pg DB from the console.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to login the postgresql shell with:

```
$ psql
```

Then, at the psql prompt,

```
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```